# How to pass data of many textbox values with POST array in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post

I have this form that contains dynamically generated textboxes filled with values (those are read from the database), and I let the user modify and save them.

But I don't know how to save the data, how to pass them to the "saver" php page (which eventually the same now, doesn't matter...)

For now, they seem like this:

```
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" id=\"category$category_id\" name=\"category$category_id\" value=\"$category_sequence\" style=\"width: 25px;\" /></td>";
```

What should be the "name" in this side, and how to reach them from the `$_POST` on the other side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got results.

I should use this way:

```
print "<input type="text" name="cat[]" value="$category_sequence" />"
```

Then an array ($_POST['cat']) will be created I can iterate through.

Or:

```
print "<input type="text" name="cat[$catId]" value="$category_sequence" />"
```

Again, iteration.

On the server side, if I stay on my original idea:

```
$i=1;
while(isset($_POST['cat'.$i]))
{
        print "There is "cat".$i item, it is processable."
        $i++;
}
```

All I wanted was this... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, take a look what you have from your form so far:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

This code will show you what you have. Then you can access any field by its name:

```
<?php
$variable = $_POST['field_name'];
?>
```

Be sure to check if there is any POST data was sent:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST) && is_array($_POST))
{
    // ...
}
?>
```

Be sure that you have needed field sent by POST form:

```
<?php
$variable = (array_key_exists('field_name', $_POST) ? $_POST['field_name'] : '');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how many textboxes will be generated. So I would like to handle them as an array or something.